# How much time would it take to get from Aqaba airport to Eilat?

Tags: israel, jordan

I can see that it should be easy to take a taxi from Aqaba airport to the Israeli border and then another taxi from the border to Eilat. How much time would it approximately take, including the border crossing? If it matters, I'm an Israeli citizen.

Comment: [This blog post](https://www.touristjordan.com/get-aqaba-eilat/) says you can do the trip in a total of half an hour, though it's not clear to me if they're saying the border crossing itself only takes five minutes or if they simply forgot to account for it and it's actually longer.

Comment: Yes, your citizenship matters a lot. :-) Last time I visited Israel (via the TLV airport), the queue for Israeli passport holders was moving very quickly. I don't know how long the border procedures on the Jordanian side can take, but if you have money to pay the exit fee, it should be fairly quick. That being said, exact waiting times can't be predicted.

Answer (score 2):

As they wrote, the actual travel time is about half an hour, not at all a long time.

The cost of a taxi on the Jordanian side is cheap, and stands at about 5 Jordanian dinars (25 NIS),
The cost of the crossing fee is NIS 107 on the Israeli side, and $15 on the Jordanian side.

Regarding waiting time, a few months ago I visited Jordan, there was no long wait. In fact, within a few minutes I crossed the border (note that an Israeli citizen needs a visa to enter Jordan)
By the way, take into account that the nearest public transport on the Israeli side is a kilometer away.

The actual crossing is carried out at the "Yitzhak Rabin border crossing".

Comment: Timatic says: "Nationals of Israel can obtain a visa on arrival" for Jordan

Comment: Yes, that's right.
It is possible to get a visa at the entrance that is valid for 6 months